# bind_param statement error

Tags: php, mysql

Is there anything wrong with my code? I have been getting fatal error for the bind_param sentence. It states "Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\1102824H\Assignment2\copyspeech.php on line 35". Please help. Thanks.

```
<?php

    session_start();

    // default user's name
    $user = '';

    // if visitor is logged in 
    $loggedIn = (!empty($_SESSION['user']));

    // since user is logged in, let us retrieve user's name from $_SESSION
    if ($loggedIn) {
        $user = $_SESSION['user'];
    } else {
        // we only allow logged in user to see this page
        // if visitor not logged in, redirect visitor to login page
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    }

    $speechID = $_GET['id'];

    // the file that contains your database credentials like username and password
    require_once('config/database.php');

    // see Lecture Webp_Week13_14_Using_PHPandMySQL(updating).pptx Slide 4 aka Step 1
    $mysqli = new mysqli($database_hostname, $database_username, $database_password, $database_name) or exit("Error connecting to database"); 

    // Slide 5 aka Step 2
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO assignment_speeches (id, subject, body, tags, image) 
                                SELECT id, subject, body, tags, image 
                                FROM assignment_speeches 
                                WHERE id = ?"); 

    // Slide 6 aka Step 3 the bind params must correspond to the ?
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $speechID); // 1 ? so we use i. we use i because  id is INT

    // Slide 7 aka Step 4
    $successfullyCopied = $stmt->execute(); 

    // Slide 8 aka Step 5
    // we won't check the delete result here.

    // Slide 9 aka Step 6 and 7
    $stmt->close();

    $mysqli->close();

    // if we successfully delete this, we 
    if ($successfullyCopied) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Successfully copied';
    } else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Unable to copy';
    }

    header('Location: homepage.php');
```

?>

Comment: your prepare failed, check `$mysqli->error`

Comment: Duplicate of the **Related** section

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP didn't bother to check the Related questions and dozens of duplicates we already have about this very same error.

Comment: @Debashis This is one `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM ...` query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your query is incorrect. That's why `prepare()` and subsequent call to `bind_param()` fail. Remove parentheses in `SELECT` clause of your query

Change

```sql
SELECT (id, subject, body,   tags, image)
```

to

```sql
SELECT id, subject, body, tags, image
```

**UPDATE** Since `id` is an `auto_increment` column you also need to exclude it from columns list to let mysql generate a new id for a row being copied

```sql
INSERT INTO assignment_speeches (subject, body, tags, image) 
SELECT subject, body, tags, image 
  FROM assignment_speeches 
 WHERE id = ?
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. However, no information was recorded in the table (assignment_speeches_copy). May I know what went wrong?

Comment: @user2646948 The only reason is that your `SELECT` doesn't return anything. In order to help you further you need to show other relevant parts of the code (e.g. how you execute your query) and your data. Did you try to execute your select directly in mysql client?

Comment: I have edited the post. Hope it helps. I am new to php and mysql. Help needed. Thank you.

Comment: Did you check that `$speechID` get a value (e.g. `echo $speechID;`)? If it has a value did you try your `SELECT... FROM assignment_speeches WHERE id = 1` (you need to substitute `1` with actual id) in mysql client tool? Does it produce the result set you expect?

Comment: I tried SELECT... FROM assignment_speeches WHERE id = 1 in mysql client tool. However, "0 rows inserted".

Comment: That means that you don't have a row with id = 1 thus there is nothing to insert.

Comment: I have a row with id = 2, but "#1062 - Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'"

Comment: Now that means that you already have a row with id=2. You need to assign a new id for a row that you insert. Is `id` auto_increment column?

Comment: Yes, my id is an auto_increment column.

Comment: See updated answer. You need to exclude id from columns list to let it assign a new id.